# Initialise Singelton once in class?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I am doing the following in order to initialise my singelton:

```
ChatDataController *box = [ChatDataController sharedInstance];
```

The problem is that i use *box in different places, for example in these methods:

```
- (void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
- (NSInteger) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

Is there a way to only have to initialise once? so that *box can be used in any method within a given class?

Comment: Simple.  Make "box" a property, and initialize it in your `init` method.  Why make things more complicated than that?

Comment: did you google "ios singleton"?

Answer (score 1):

Put this code in your `ChatDataController`

```
+ (ChatDataController *)sharedInstance
{
    static ChatDataController *object = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        object = [[ChatDataController alloc] init];
    });
    return object;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to only have to initialise once?

If `ChatDataController` is a singleton it can only be initialised once.

`[ChatDataController sharedInstance]` should always return the same instance and only `alloc] init]` the first time it is called.

If, as you mentioned in one of the comments, you already have your singleton, then simply call `[ChatDataController sharedInstance]` whenever you need the shared instance. There is no need to store the pointer to the object in a property.

Comment: I have given +1 to this answer as I believe it doesn't deserve a -1 as it is correct and informative.

Answer (score -1):

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CocoaObjects/CocoaObjects.html

In "Creating a Singleton Instance"

```
static MyGizmoClass *sharedGizmoManager = nil;

+ (MyGizmoClass*)sharedManager
{
    if (sharedGizmoManager == nil) {
        sharedGizmoManager = [[super allocWithZone:NULL] init];
    }
    return sharedGizmoManager;
}
```

Comment: I already have my Singelton class ready, im wondering how to use `MyGizmoClass` :)

Comment: You call it like this : yourGizmoClass = [MyGizmoClass sharedManager];

Answer (score -1):

try this one:- create macro in .pch file

first import class

```
#import"ChatDataController.h"
```

then create macro
(sharedInstance must be  class method)

```
#define box ([ChatDataController sharedInstance])
```

after that u you can use this object in all classes

Comment: The chat data controller does not belong in the PCH, and that macro will just make your code look confusing, because `box` will look like a local variable.

Comment: then pls post best solution if you have any